# Compare and add word if not found in the list

Tags: python, list, sorting, compare, text-files

This is the code i am trying:

```py
file1 = open("romeo.txt")
list_orig=[]
list_distinct=[]

for line in file1:
 words=line.split()
  list_orig=list_orig+words
  for word in words:
    if word in list_distinct:continue
    list_distinct= list_distinct+word
print (list_distinct)
```

Could you please help me correct the code? Not getting desired results.

I am looking for help in comparing word from romeo.txt file and compare each word with the existing list of words. (If word exists in list then discard it, if word doesn't exist then add it.) Print the sorted list.

Comment: Did you mean to use a `set()`? You can convert that to a list later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

''''

```
with open("romeo.txt", mode='r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
list_distinct = []

for line in data:
  words = line.split()
  for word in words:
    if word not in list_distinct:
      list_distinct.append(word)
list_distinct.sort()
print(list_distinct)
```

''''

Comment: Romeo.txt contains following: But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief

Comment: Output looks like:                                                                                                                                   ['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to use list_orig.

```
    with open("romeo.txt", mode='r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    list_distinct = []

    for line in data:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if word not in list_distinct:
                list_distinct.append(word)
    print(list_distinct)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do that could be to fill a list with the distinct words:

```py
file1 = open("romeo.txt")
list_existing=['one']
list_distinct=[]

for line in file1:
    words=line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in list_existing:
            list_distinct.append(word)
print (list_distinct)
```

In this example, romeo.txt is:

```
this is a test
one
```

The output is then:

```bash
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

Answer (score 0):

The short and simple fix: you can only concatenate lists.

```
# ...
list_distinct = list_distinct + [word]
```

The approach is however questionable, as you keep creating new list objects. Better to keep expanding the same list:

```
list_distinct.append(word)
```

Better yet, use a set or dict for the membership test. It has much better performance (`O(1)`) than a list (`O(N)`). The whole principle can be shortened to:

```
file1 = open("romeo.txt")

# build list in one go!
list_orig = [w for line in file1 for w in line.split()]  

# build list of unique elements in order of occurrence
list_distinct = [*dict.fromkeys(list_orig)]  # dict maintains insertion order

print(list_distinct)
```